# Google Chart, Different color in for each bar by add in $.each

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have this Google Bar Chart:

```
function drawChart(result) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hour');
        data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
        var dataArray = [];
        **var colorAdd = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];**

        $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
            dataArray.push([obj.Name, obj.TimeHour, **ADD TO THIS**]);
        });
        data.addRows(dataArray);

        var columnChartOptions = {
            title: "All Hour",
            height: 400,
            legend: { position: "none" },
        };

        var columnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_div'));
        columnChart.draw(data, columnChartOptions);
    }
```

I return data from controller to view and push to chart by $.each

In this code i can add name color i want to colum color.

But If i want to add Array color for change color each bar i should use?

I try to add color:[ ] to columnChartOptions but only first color in array add to chart.

Can anyone help Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `colors` option applies each color in the provided array,
to each y-axis column (series) in the data table.

if you only have one series, then only one color will be applied.

if you have four colors in the colors array,
then you would have to have four y-axis columns for each color to be applied.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hour A');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hour B');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hour C');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hour D');
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  drawChart([{
    Name: 'Category 1',
    TimeHourA: 1,
    TimeHourB: 2,
    TimeHourC: 3,
    TimeHourD: 4
  }, {
    Name: 'Category 2',
    TimeHourA: 2,
    TimeHourB: 4,
    TimeHourC: 6,
    TimeHourD: 8
  }]);
});

function drawChart(result) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Hour A');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Hour B');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Hour C');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Hour D');
  var dataArray = [];
  var colorAdd = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];

  $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([obj.Name, obj.TimeHourA, obj.TimeHourB, obj.TimeHourC, obj.TimeHourD]);
  });
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  var columnChartOptions = {
    colors: colorAdd,
    title: "All Hour",
    height: 400,
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };

  var columnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_div'));
  columnChart.draw(data, columnChartOptions);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_div"></div>
```

---

if you only have one series in the data table,
and you wish to color each bar a different color,
the only option is to use the style column role.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  drawChart([{
    Name: 'A',
    TimeHour: 1
  }, {
    Name: 'B',
    TimeHour: 2
  }, {
    Name: 'C',
    TimeHour: 3
  }, {
    Name: 'D',
    TimeHour: 4
  }]);
});

function drawChart(result) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Hour');
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
  var dataArray = [];
  var colorAdd = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];

  $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([obj.Name, obj.TimeHour, colorAdd[i]]);
  });
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  var columnChartOptions = {
    title: "All Hour",
    height: 400,
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };

  var columnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_div'));
  columnChart.draw(data, columnChartOptions);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_div"></div>
```